# GLSL layout attribute number

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I was trying out a shader example to draw a triangle with the RGB interpolated across the vertices, and assumed that using

```
layout (location = 0)in vec4 vertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 VertexColor;
```

in the vertex shader would work, since the 4 float colors immediately follow 4 float vertices in the array.  However, it always drew a solid red triangle.  So I tried location = 4 only to get a black screen.  Experimenting further gave a blue triangle for location = 2, and finally got the interpolated result with location = 3.

My question is, how was I expected to know to enter 3 as the location?  The vertex array looks like this:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {  -1.5,-1.5, 0.0, 1.0,    //first 3D vertex
                         1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,    //first color
                         0.0, 1.5, 0.0, 1.0,    //second vertex
                         0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,    //second color
                         1.5,-1.5, 0.0, 1.0,    //third vertex
                         0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,};  //third color
```

note: edited the original layout=1 from layout = 3 in first code block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

each location can hold 4 floats (a single vec4), So a valid option would also be:

```
layout (location = 0)in vec4 vertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 VertexColor;
```

What dictates where what attribute comes from is the set of glVertexAttribPointer calls.

these are the ones I would expect for the glsl declaration above (assuming you use a VBO)

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(float)*4*2, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(float)*4*2, sizeof(float)*4);
```

Comment: I was using vertex buffer arrays with glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 32, &vertices[0]); \n glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 32, &vertices[4]);

Comment: ah, glVertexPointer is deprecated along with all the other fixed function pipeline functions.

Comment: Why use 64 for the stride? With two interleaved attributes using 4 floats each, I believe the stride is 32. Or `sizeof(float)*4*2`.